# Image archive instead of css sprites?

Tags: image, archive, css-sprites

**Context**: http transfer of a collection of images in a responsive web page. Images could be icon-sized, but they could also be larger. Want to reduce the number of GET requests, but also be able to resize images as required.

**Standard solution**: Use [css sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). In my case, css sprites got too complicated for me as the window resized - either a bit of some image appears, or the wrong image appears.

**Question:** Is it meaningful to instead transfer a single 'tar-like' archive file that the browser will 'untar'? This way it's possible to access each image *file* as opposed to css tricks like background-position.

I know that for html/css/js we can set content-encoding to gzip. What about images? It's not the compression (these are images), it's the 'directory structure' of a tar-like or gzip-like archive.

Comment: http://kaioa.com/node/99 talks about this. I'm researching this now (came across your question on the way). Also: https://www.google.com/#q=alternative+to+image+sprites+css